# Закрытие соединения с MySQL в Golang

Tags: mysql, golang

Не пойму когда нужно закрывать соединение MySQL.

```
package main

import (
    ...
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open(...)
    http.HandleFunc("/", TestFunc)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
    db.Close()
}
```

В данном примере будет закрыто соединение или нет? Как я понимаю, функция `main` не завершится до тех пор пока работает `ListenAndServe`, и нужно закрывать соединение в конце каждой `HandleFunc`?

Comment: "нужно закрывать соединение в конце каждой HandleFunc". Разве ваша утверждение не показывает, что соединение нужно открывать в HandleFunc? В остальном распределением ресурсов соединений должен заниматься пул соединений, который реализован в пакете. Т.е. это не должно быть заботой вашего функционала.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. В данном примере будет закрыто соединение или НЕТ?

В такой постановке задачи - нет, соединение не будет закрыто.

> 2. Как я понимаю функция main не завершится до тех пор пока работает ListenAndServe

Да, `main` не завершится. Более того, она не завершится в принципе, поскольку единственный вариант завершить программу после `http.ListenAndServer` (если не использовать дополнительные библиотеки) - послать ей `SIGTERM`, после чего она просто завершается не заботясь об исполнении последней директивы из `main`. К слову, `defer db.Close()` тоже не отработает, поскольку `main` не завершилась.

> 3. и нужно закрывать соединение в конце каждой HandleFunc ?

Соединение не нужно закрывать совсем. Внутри `db/sql` используется [connection pool](http://go-database-sql.org/connection-pool.html), т.е. один раз указав `db.SetMaxIdleConns` и `db.SetMaxOpenConns` об управлении соединениями можно забыть.

Если для вас критично закрывать соединение, единственный вариант - перехватывать команды на завершение и закрывать соединение. Код примерно такой

```
imports (
    ...
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open(...)

    c := make(chan os.Signal, 2)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)
    go func() {
        <-c
        db.Close()
        os.Exit(1)
    }()

    http.HandleFunc("/", TestFunc)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Но, повторюсь, в реальности это бесполезное занятие.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте специальный оператор defer, который позволяет отложить вызов указанной функции до тех пор, пока не завершится текущая:

```
func main() {
    db, err = sql.Open("mysql", "...")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer db.Close()
    http.HandleFunc("/", TestFunc)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

http://golang-book.ru/chapter-07-functions.html

Comment: Ответа на вопрос я не вижу! я знаю, что такое дефер и как он работает, вопрос состоит в другом.

Answer (score 0):

Если закрытие соединения с MySQL необходимо, то это можно реализовать создав две handler-функции `HandleFuncBefore` и `HandleFuncAfter`.

Идея простая: в первой открываем соединение, во второй его закрываем, а остальные handler-функции, собственно, должны наследовать `HandleFuncBefore` и вызывать после обработки `HandleFuncAfter`.

Пример с использованием фреймворка [Gin](https://gin-gonic.github.io/gin/), в нём можно описать идею немного проще:

```
// код для версии v1.0-rc.2
func DatabaseConnection() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        // Выполнение кода перед запросом (HandleFuncBefore)

        db, err = sql.Open("mysql", "...")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }

        c.Set("db", db)

        // Обработка текущего запроса
        c.Next()

        // Выполнение кода после запроса (HandleFuncAfter) 

        db.Close()
    }
}

func main() {
    r := gin.New()
    r.Use(DatabaseConnection())

    r.GET("/test", func(c *gin.Context) {
        db := c.MustGet("db").(*sql.DB)
        // использование db
    })

    // Запуск сервера Gin
    r.Run(":8080")
}
```